# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un documento a otro y luego descargarlo?

Tags: c#, mvc, visual-studio-2015

tengo el siguiente código:

```
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DocX doc = DocX.Create(stream);
        // Load a document.
        using (DocX document = DocX.Load(@"C:\Users\soportetj\Downloads\Test.docx"))
        {
            // Check if all the replace patterns are used in the loaded document.
            document.ReplaceText("NameField", "Ing. Leonel Brayan Perez Ramirez");
            document.ReplaceText("UniversityField", "UTT");
            document.ReplaceText("PersonField", "Ingeniero en sistemas, MAT 0316111900");
            document.ReplaceText("ZoneField", "Terrazas del valle, Av. Paseo de las lomas #9189");
            document.ReplaceText("DelegationField", "Tijuana Baja California");
            document.ReplaceText("PhoneField", "Teléfono: (664)-104-4582");

            document.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\soportetj\Downloads\Out.docx");
        }

        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "FileName.docx");

    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar lo que está en "document" a "doc" para posteriormente descargarlo como archivo de Word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te funcionará lo siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    DocX doc = DocX.Create(stream);
    // Load a document.
    using (DocX document = DocX.Load(@"C:\Users\soportetj\Downloads\Test.docx"))
    {
        // Check if all the replace patterns are used in the loaded document.
        document.ReplaceText("NameField", "Ing. Leonel Brayan Perez Ramirez");
        document.ReplaceText("UniversityField", "UTT");
        document.ReplaceText("PersonField", "Ingeniero en sistemas, MAT 0316111900");
        document.ReplaceText("ZoneField", "Terrazas del valle, Av. Paseo de las lomas #9189");
        document.ReplaceText("DelegationField", "Tijuana Baja California");
        document.ReplaceText("PhoneField", "Teléfono: (664)-104-4582");

        document.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\soportetj\Downloads\Out.docx");
    }

    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "FileName.docx");
}
```

Otra opción sería:

```
public ActionResult Save()
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                using (DocX document = DocX.Load(@"C:\Users\soportetj\Downloads\Test.docx"))
                {
                    // Check if all the replace patterns are used in the loaded document.
                    document.ReplaceText("NameField", "Ing. Leonel Brayan Perez Ramirez");
                    document.ReplaceText("UniversityField", "UTT");
                    document.ReplaceText("PersonField", "Ingeniero en sistemas, MAT 0316111900");
                    document.ReplaceText("ZoneField", "Terrazas del valle, Av. Paseo de las lomas #9189");
                    document.ReplaceText("DelegationField", "Tijuana Baja California");
                    document.ReplaceText("PhoneField", "Teléfono: (664)-104-4582");

                    mainPart.Document = new Document(
                    new Body(
                        new Paragraph(
                            new Run(
                                new Text(document.Text)))));

                }
            }
        }

        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "Test.docx");
    }
```

Comment: Mmm de hecho así me trae el archivo vacío

Comment: Agregué otra opción. Espero te resulte útil

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Logré solucionarlo así:

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    DocX doc = DocX.Create(stream);
    // Load a document.
    DocX document = DocX.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Test.docx"));

    // Check if all the replace patterns are used in the loaded document.
    document.ReplaceText("NameField", "Ing. Leonel Brayan Perez Ramirez");
    document.ReplaceText("UniversityField", "UTT");
    document.ReplaceText("PersonField", "Ingeniero en sistemas, MAT 0316111900");
    document.ReplaceText("ZoneField", "Terrazas del valle, Av. Paseo de las lomas #9189");
    document.ReplaceText("DelegationField", "Tijuana Baja California");
    document.ReplaceText("PhoneField", "Teléfono: (664)-104-4582");
    doc.InsertDocument(document);
    doc.Save();

    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "FileName.docx");
```